# Node.JS MySQL waiting for query results

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to make a function that query data to MySQL, and wait for the result.

```
const results = await message.client.db.query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE condition");
console.log(results);
```

My issue is that results doesn't contain the raw data as I would expect it, but a query object :

```
<ref *1> Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    error: [Function (anonymous)],
    packet: [Function (anonymous)],
    timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
    end: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: [Function (anonymous)],
...
    _connectCalled: true,
    state: 'authenticated',
    threadId: 27,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

I have been looking for a doc on that Object, and I couldn't find it. I suppose it is a sort of Promise, as the Query object is returned before the results are received :

```
console.log("1 - Before Query");
const results = await message.client.db.query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE condition", async function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("2 - Query result : ");
    console.log(result);
});
console.log("3 - After Query");
console.log(results);   

OUTPUT : 
1 - Before Query
3 - After Query
<The Query Object>
2 - Query result : 
<An array with my data>
```

I have seen a lot of example where people use `await connection.query("...")` to wait for the results, and I don't understand where does this Query object comes from.

I know I can wait for the result with something like that :

```
    message.client.db.query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE condition", async function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        do_something(result);
    });
```

But I first find it really heavy, and hard to use when you do a lot of requests.
Also I need an async function that return a value from database, and since `await connection.query("...")` can't wait for the result, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: what mysql driver library do you use? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql? https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2?

Comment: it's not a problem with waiting for result, but what mysql library you using for nodejs ? if you want a function then you can create ```async function()``` and ```await``` for result but your library should return a promise resolve result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using mysql2 package to connect to the database you can do something like this:

```
await con1.promise().query("your query here")
    .then( ([rows,fields]) => {
        your var = rows[0]['field1'];
        return nome_completo;
    })
    .catch(console.log)
```

Where con1 is the connection you defined. With promise() you are promisifying your query so you can use await